# Json to Python converting

Tags: python, json

I have this sample json data, and need to grab only the MAC addresses so I can convert the mac to a list of manufacturers later.

```
[
{
    "aps": {
        "00:20:90:B3:16:25": {
            "ssid": "",
            "encryption": "Open",
            "hidden": 1,
            "channel": 11,
            "signal": -23,
            "wps": 0,
            "last_seen": 1594356454,
            "clients": []
        },
        "06:AA:A0:84:7F:D8": {
            "ssid": "",
            "encryption": "Open",
            "hidden": 1,
            "channel": 6,
            "signal": -75,
            "wps": 0,
            "last_seen": 1594356452,
            "clients": []
        },
        "1E:51:A4:D4:B7:29": {
            "ssid": "",
            "encryption": "WPA Mixed PSK (CCMP TKIP)",
            "hidden": 1,
            "channel": 11,
            "signal": -63,
            "wps": 0,
            "last_seen": 1594356448,
            "clients": []
        }
    }
}
]
```

This is my python program so far, but im not sure how to isolate the MAC address

```
import json

f = open('recon_data.json',)

data = json.load(f)

print(data["aps"])

f.close()
```

I get an error every time I run the program weather im asking for aps or ssid information

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "recon.py", line 12, in 
print(data["ssid"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `data` is a list. You probably want the first item: `data[0]['aps']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the data you're loading is a list. Try `data[0]["aps"]`

As for getting all the mac addresses they are the keys in that dict so you can just use list on that inner dict to get all the keys:

```
import json

with open('recon_data.json') as f
    data = json.load(f)

print(list(data[0]['aps']))
```

This will print a list of all the MAC addresses

```
['00:20:90:B3:16:25', '06:AA:A0:84:7F:D8', '1E:51:A4:D4:B7:29']
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you. when you load json does it just put it into a dictionary then?

Comment: It loads it as it's stored *(considering it's stored in a way it can parse)*

Comment: How do i get the ssid from the json file?

Comment: `[d['ssid'] for d in data[0]['aps']]`